# How to highlight cells on two different tables that have the same data when hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have two different HTML tables that may or may not have same values. Im looking for a way to hightlight individual cells in the tables that have the same value. For example in the table below, when the mouse hovers over a 1 in the first table, it will highlight this cell as well as all of the cells in table 2 that have a 1 in them as well.

I'm able to highlight invidual cells with some simple CSS but dont know how to highlight corresponding cells on different tables.

```
<table id="table1" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </td>
</table>

..........

<table id="table2" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </td>
</table>
```

The given answer worked for this example code, however I was hoping to implement it using user inputted tables such as the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function generateTable()
{
    var rows1 = document.getElementById('rows1').value;
    var columns1 = document.getElementById('columns1').value;
    var tableBegin = '<table border="1">\n';
    var body = '';

    for(var i=0; i < rows1; i++)
    {
        body += '<tr>';
        for(var j=0; j < columns1; j++)
        {
            body += '<td>';
            body += Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
            body += '</td>'
        }
        body += '</tr>\n';
    }
    var endTable = '</table>';
document.getElementById('firstTable').innerHTML = tableBegin + body + endTable;
}


function generateTable2()
{
    var rows2 = document.getElementById('rows2').value;
    var columns2 = document.getElementById('columns2').value;
    var tableBegin2 = '<table border="1">\n';
    var body2 = '';

    for(var i=0; i < rows2; i++)
    {
        body2 += '<tr>';
        for(var j=0; j < columns2; j++)
        {
            body2 += '<td>';
            body2 += Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
            body2 += '</td>'
        }
        body2 += '</tr>\n';
    }
    var endTable2 = '</table>';
document.getElementById('secondTable').innerHTML = tableBegin2 + body2 + endTable2;
}
</script>    
<form name="makeTable1">
 Table 1<br>
   Rows:    <input type="text" name="rows1" id="rows1"><br>
   Columns: <input type="text" name="columns1" id="columns1"><br><br>

<input name="generate" type="button" value="Generate Table" onclick='generateTable();'/>
</form>


   Table 2<br>
   Rows:    <input type="text" name="rows2" id="rows2"><br>
   Columns: <input type="text" name="columns2" id="columns2"><br>

<form name="makeTable2">

<input name="generate" type="button" value="Generate Table" onclick='generateTable2();'/>
</form>

 <div id="firstTable"></div>
```

How do I modify the answer to be implemented on these tables?

Comment: `onmouseover`-`onmouseout` events could help you out. However, it could be useful to tag the cells with some Row-Column data, like `data-rc="1-2"`...

Comment: @ZorgoZ this thing you say is in js not css

Comment: please add your code in codepen or codesandbox to people help you  thanks

Comment: @Abal Please do not ask for code to be posted to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Runnable code can be inserted right here in Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: ok so put your code here how we can see that in action

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this (supposing JQuery is acceptable for you):

```js
$(() => { // we need to attach listeners after the dom is ready
  $('td').on('mouseover', (e)=> { // attach handler on TD-s to 'hover' equivalent event
    let the = $(e.currentTarget).text() // get current element text
    $("td").filter((_,x) => $(x).text() == the).addClass('hover') // find all TD-s with matching content and add marker class
  })
  
  $('td').on('mouseout', ()=> { // attach focus lost on TD-s 
    $(`td`).removeClass('hover') // remove marker class from all TD-s
  })
})
```

```css
.hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>

..........

<table id="table2" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This helps a bit, but I was thinking more based on the values, not the positions on the table. So like if the first 1 is hovered over in the first table, all of the ones in the second table would also highlight

Comment: The question is not tagged with JQuery. Also, good answers are more than just "try this" followed by some code. They explain the problem and the solution.

Comment: Dear @ScottMarcus You are perfectly right. But that both can be neatly satisfied _after_ OP confirms that this is the result he is expecting.

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: @mojuy11 please tag your question with JQuery in this case.

Comment: @ScottMarcus A good answer help OP... everything else is politics.

Comment: First post so I apologize for not specifying, however this was what i was looking for

Comment: Actually no, it's not. Please read ["How to answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and try to understand the platform you are on. Stack Overflow has a purpose and guidelines for its use.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Satisfied?